# jQuery .find("body").html() == null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page called test.html, here is it's content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
    <title></title> </head> <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #d9d9d9;">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="NewsLetterPreview.aspx?NewsletterID=1" id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTA3NzM3OTc4N2Rkkk3StA9iwyEdCoR43JPpw6OyRHubNTnbXatTbxCXsVA=" />
    </div>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

I then have another page which I am using $.get to get the content of the page:

```
$.get("test.html", function (data) {
            alert($(data).find("body").html());
        });
```

However the `alert($(data).find("body").html())` returns null. It does the same for the `alert($(data).find("form").html())` also. Only if I specify `alert($(data).find("div").html())` does it return the input field.

How can I select the body / form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace your body with fetched HTML, this should do it.

```
$.get("test.html", function (data) {
            $(body).html(data);
        });
```

**EDIT:**

Missread your question.

It'd suggest you to use json or .replace() instead.

Example: `alert(data.replace(/^.*?\<body\>(.*?)\<\/body\>.*$/, "$1"));`

If you want body tags included: `alert(data.replace(/^.*?(\<body\>.*?\<\/body\>).*$/, "$1"));`

I don't think jquery can work with HTML the way you wish. Either include it in the code and then use regular functions or find another workaround.

Comment: The question is not how to replace body, is how to get a body element in returned data

Comment: alert($("body").html(data).html()); <- this worked, yay & thanks. What my ultimate goal is, is to remove the <form> and <input> elements. For bonus man points can you offer any help?

Comment: Should be enough to insert: `$('input, form').remove();` after that.

Comment: How'd you mean sorry? After where?

Comment: After you've inserted the HTML in your body: `$("body").html(data);`

Comment: But $('input, form').remove(); does not reference my HTML block? If I have var myHtml = $("html").html(data).html(); how would I remove the input and form elements from myHtml var?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the solution, but I think I can shed some light on the problem...

From here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use
>   the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert
>   it into the current document. During this process, some browsers
>   filter out certain elements such as , , or 
>   elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative
>   of the original string passed.

Which means that on *some browsers* the HTML string being input has the form, head, and body tags stripped out before jQuery processes the string - so it is as if your returned string only has the div and it's contents.